# How can i balance a binary search tree with an array without using recursion?

Tags: c, arrays, iteration, binary-search-tree

My problems are: How can I check the elements in the array ? How can I set up the loop on the array ?

This is the recursive code:

```
Tree BuildBalancedTree(Tree T, void **array, int inf, int sup, int(*comp)(void *, void *))
{
    int mid;

    if(inf < sup)
    {
        mid = (inf + sup) / 2;

        T = insertNode_it(T, array[mid], comp);

        T = BuildBalancedTree(T, array, inf, mid, comp);
        T = BuildBalancedTree(T, array, mid + 1, sup, comp);
    }

    return T;
}
```

EDIT:
I think i found how to solve it:

```
while((Top(st) != -1) || inf <= sup){

    while(inf <= sup){
        mid = (inf + sup) / 2;
        T = insertNode_it(T, array[mid], comp);     

        /* here i'm using a stack to store the array's boundaries */
        st = push_int(st, mid + 1);
        st = push_int(st, sup);         
        sup = mid - 1;

    }

    if((sup < inf) && (Top(st) != -1)){
        sup = Top(st);
        st = pop_int(st);

        inf = Top(st);
        st = pop_int(st);
    }

}
```

It does work.
However do you think i should change something ?

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Trees are, by definition, an isomorphic data structure. This means that they "repeat" themselves, which makes them perfect for recursion.

Also, speaking about the equivalence between recursion and induction, the induction is a particular case of recursion, called tail recursion, where you have just one recursive call at the end of your method. For trees, 2 recursive calls are required, which makes it harder to convert to an iterative form. Also, the iterative form will definitely be more complicated than the recursive one and probably less efficient.

Since there is no immediate iterative equivalent to the recursion required to traverse (or do any operation) on a tree from the reasons shown above, one way to do it iteratively is to simulate recursion by having a stack that acts as the call stack of the "real" recurison.